# Is it possible to limit ps column output to a specified length starting from the back?

Tags: command-line, unix

Can you limit the size of the COMMAND column field output by ps by removing chgaracters from the end.

Or only show certain fields when executing `ps aux`.

So, I'd like to only display the first 10 results with only the last 100 characters of the "COMMAND" field. Is this possible?

Comment: Showing certain fields is a separate question for which the first step is look at the man page for ps `man ps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some small unix programs chained together, you could do this-

```
ps -ax -o command | head -n 10 | rev | cut -c 1-100 | rev
```

`ps -ax -o command`  prints only the command and arguemnts

`Head` prints the first 10 lines

`rev` reverses the string

`cut` produces the last 100 characters in reverse

`rev` reverses the string back

Using `awk` a text processing language-

```
ps -ax -o command | awk 'NR <=10 { print substr( $0, length($0) - 100, length($0) ) }'
```